# How to calculate unique session id per user per minute in a click stream dataset using Spark-SQL?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Imagine that we have a clickstream dataset having millions of rows. And we want to calculate unique session-id per user per minute.**
**Sample Dataset** :

```
+------+-------------------+
|userId|clicktime          |
+------+-------------------+
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:17:50|
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:17:59|
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:19:59|
|1038  |2009-05-21 13:17:50|
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:17:00|
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:17:50|
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:17:59|
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:19:59|
|1038  |2009-05-21 13:19:59|
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:20:50|
+------+-------------------+
```

**I have written a code in Spark-Scala to solve this but it is not an optimal solution for dataset having millions of rows. I want a better solution than what I have implemented. Below is the source code of my implementation:**

```
val dfWithLag = rawData
      .withColumn("lag", lag(col("clicktime"), 1)
        .over(Window.partitionBy("userId") orderBy ("clicktime")).cast("timestamp"))
      .withColumn("lag_diff", unix_timestamp($"clicktime") - unix_timestamp($"lag"))
      .withColumn("lag_diff", when(col("lag_diff").isNull, 0).otherwise(col("lag_diff")))
      .orderBy("userId", "clicktime")


    val finalDf = dfWithLag.repartition(col("userId")).mapPartitions(partition => {
      var sessionId = scala.util.Random
      var currentSessionId = sessionId.nextInt().toInt
      val newPartition = partition
        .map(record => {
          ClickStream(record.getInt(0),record.getTimestamp(1), record.getTimestamp(2),
            record.getLong(3), {
              val timeDiff = record.getLong(3)
              if (timeDiff > 60) {
                currentSessionId = sessionId.nextInt.toInt
                currentSessionId
              }
              else if (timeDiff == 0) currentSessionId
              else currentSessionId
            }
          )
        }).toList
      newPartition.iterator
    })
    (Encoders.product[ClickStream])

    rawData.show(false)
    finalDf.drop("lag").drop("lagDiff").show(false)
```

**Output of the code:**

```
+------+-------------------+-----------+
|userId|clickTime          |sessionId  |
+------+-------------------+-----------+
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:17:00|1049786501 |
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:17:50|1049786501 |
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:17:59|1049786501 |
|1037  |2009-05-21 13:19:59|-1649908351|
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:17:50|-1794290301|
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:17:59|-1794290301|
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:19:59|668855070  |
|1039  |2009-04-21 13:20:50|668855070  |
|1038  |2009-05-21 13:17:50|1149727960 |
|1038  |2009-05-21 13:19:59|-95969967  |
+------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply get date without seconds using `date_format` and then create your unique sessionId by `hash` function. In your example you are using `scala.util.Random` without seed and because of this your sessionId may not be unique.

```
df.withColumn("sessionId", hash('userId, date_format('clicktime,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))).show()
```

```
    +------+-------------------+
    |userId|          clicktime|
    +------+-------------------+
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:17:50|
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:17:59|
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:19:59|
    |  1038|2009-05-21 13:17:50|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:17:00|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:17:50|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:17:59|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:19:59|
    |  1038|2009-05-21 13:19:59|
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:20:50|
    +------+-------------------+

    +------+-------------------+-----------+
    |userId|          clicktime|  sessionId|
    +------+-------------------+-----------+
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:17:50|-1768577078|
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:17:59|-1768577078|
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:19:59| -443001140|
    |  1038|2009-05-21 13:17:50| 1660590339|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:17:00| 1360561347|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:17:50| 1360561347|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:17:59| 1360561347|
    |  1037|2009-05-21 13:19:59|  925508976|
    |  1038|2009-05-21 13:19:59| 1148270137|
    |  1039|2009-04-21 13:20:50| 1342597130|
    +------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: The minute is not the deciding factor here. The requirement is, if the gap between the two clicks > 60 secs then, change the session Id, else id remains the same. Your query will fail in this case.  e.g. first click is at 12:10:50, second at 12:11:12, gap between these two timestamps is not more than 60 secs. Hence, session Id should be same.